# inverse trigonometric equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

first question i finished, but im not sure if notation is correct? second one i couldn't finish. third one i don't know if i can even start because of typo on paper

## **1.**

$$ \cos^2(x)-0.2\sin(x) = 0.9; \\ [0^{\circ},360^{\circ})$$

use identity

$(1-\sin^2(x))-\frac{1}{5}\sin(x) = \frac{9}{10}$
$-\sin^2(x)-\frac{1}{5}\sin(x) = \frac{9}{10} - \frac{10}{10}$
$-\sin^2(x)-\frac{1}{5}\sin(x) + \frac{1}{10} = 0$

negate to factor

$$\sin^2(x)+\frac{1}{5}\sin(x) - \frac{1}{10} = 0$$

can't factor, use quadratic formula

$$A=1,B=\frac{2}{10},C=-\frac{1}{10}$$
$$\sin(x) = \frac{-\frac{2}{10}\pm \sqrt{\frac{4}{100}+(\frac{4}{10})}}{2}$$

$$\sin(x) = \frac{-\frac{2}{10}\pm \sqrt{\frac{11}{25}}}{2}$$

$$\sin(x) = 0.231662479$$ 
$$\sin(x) = -0.431662479$$

$$\sin^{-1}(0.231662479) = 13.39496861 $$
$$\sin^{-1}(-0.431662479) = -25.57311158$$
$$x = 13.39496861^{\circ}$$
$$x = -25.57311158^{\circ}$$

final answer

$$x = 13.39496861^{\circ} + k180^{\circ}, k \text{ any integer}$$
$$x = -25.57311158^{\circ} + k180^{\circ}, k \text{ any integer}$$

correct? this is how my book writes it

## **2.**

$$\sin(2x)\cos(x)+\cos(2x)\sin(x)=\cos(3x) \quad\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$

use identity $\sin(3x)$

$$\sin(3x)=\cos(3x)$$

$$\tan(3x)=1$$

$$\tan^{-1}(1)=.785398163 \rm{rad}$$
$$ x = \frac{.785398163}{3}$$

final answer

$$x=.261799388rad +\pi k, k \text{ any integer}$$

## **3.**

[image]

this is exactly how the problem is written on the paper, this must be a typo since there is no equal sign? I think the plus sign was meant to be a equal sign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

For **2** $$\sin(2x)\cos(x)+\cos(2x)\sin(x)=\sin(2x+x)=\sin(3x)$$ 
$$\cos(2x)\cos(x)-\sin(2x)\sin(x)=\cos(2x+x)=\cos(3x)$$

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: @enzotib. Thanks for editing for the oooold man !

Comment: for #2(edited) is this right? any comment on #3 not being a equation? therefore shouldn't be attempted?

Comment: @hit. For **2**, remember the develpment of $\sin(a+b)$ and $\cos(a+b)$. For **3**, you could disclaim the problem since you do not know what has to be done. But you could also say : OK, let us assume that we have to solve the expression for $=0$; use the half angle formula for $\cos(x)$, replace $x=2y$ to get an equation.One obvious solution is $y=0$; another is $y=\pi/4$,